# Calculate amount of ETH and USDC after minting a position in uniswap v3

Tags: uniswap, ethereumjs, uniswapv3

I would love help in this aspect as I am a novice:

Backdrop:

- UNISWAP V3 ETH/USDC pool
- Current tick of 202,690
- Position upper tick of 203,000
- Position lower tick of 202, 000
- Position value in USDC of 50,000

How can I calculate the amount of ETH and USDC I obtained from my minting of position.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out the proportion in which USDC and ETH have to be added. Then divide up the 50,000 USC in this proportion.

A tricky aspect to remember is that for the USDC/WETH pool on the mainnet, the asset `X` is USDC and the asset `Y` is WETH, meaning that the price is for one unit of USDC per one unit of ETH, rather than the more natural other way around.

In more detail (relying on the math formulas from the [whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf) and [the math explainer](https://atiselsts.github.io/pdfs/uniswap-v3-liquidity-math.pdf)):

1. Switch from ticks to square roots of prices, as they are used in liquidity computations.

```
price = 1.0001 ** 202690      # price
sp = 1.0001 ** (202690 // 2)  # sqrt(price)
sa = 1.0001 ** (202000 // 2)  # sqrt(price_a)
sb = 1.0001 ** (203000 // 2)  # sqrt(price_b)
```

2. Find out the proportion of the assets. To do that, fix a unit liquidity `L=1`, and compute the amounts of ETH and USDC for that liquidity.

```
L = 1
x_unit = L * (sb - sp) / (sp * sb)
y_unit = L * (sp - sa)
```

3. Divide the initial capital in the right proportions

```
V_capital = 50000 * (10**6) # because USDC has 6 decimals
V_capital *= price
V_unit = x_unit * price + y_unit
n_units = V_capital / V_unit
x = n_units * x_unit
y = n_units * y_unit
```

4. Scale the result by the number of the decimals of the respective tokens:

```
x = x / 1e6
y = y / 1e18
```

5. Check that the result is correct:

```
adjusted_price = (1 / price) * 1e18 / 1e6
pos_value_usdc = y * adjusted_price + x
print(pos_value_usdc) # 50000.0
```

The calculations above ignores any price impact that would come from using the pool itself to swap the assets. If you want to go deeper and account for that, here's a [Desmos calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oiv0rti0ss) by Dan Robinson that maximizes the amount of liquidity added to the pool if the initial assets are in the wrong balances, and need to be swapped using the pool itself.